# How do I read the element from a html which does not have an id?

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following html snippet from which I am extracting the username and password element ; then sending the username and password and click on the submit button.

```
<form name="sign_in" action=https://www.amazon.in/ap/widget method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="sessionId" value="276-3860748-2761707" />
  <input type="hidden" name="widgetToken" value="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:SkFuUUJZQW8zS0lhSm5RN3dsWUVlV0ttdmErZ3J2N3BjYW5naVFKTitOND06MQ==">
  <input type="hidden" name="path" value="/gp/associates/login/login.html" />
  <input type="hidden" name="query" value="returl=/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html&amp;retquery="/>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sign-in" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="1" />
  <div class="formLabel">Email address</div>
  <div class="formInput"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="text" /></div>
  <div class="formLabel">Password </div>
  <div class="formInput"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text" /></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" >Stay Signed In<br>
  <p id="signin">
    <input type="image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/sign-in-md-pri._V138360034_.gif"  width="69" alt="Sign In" value="Sign In" height="22" border="0" />
    <a id="needHelp" href="http://affiliate-program.amazon.in/gp/associates/login/help.html">Need help?</a>
  </p>
<script id="fwicm-script" type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/login/fwcim._V342129342_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    fwcim.profile()
</script>

</form>
```

I am using selenium firefox driver . My code snippet is -

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

WebElement emailField=driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
emailField.sendKeys(login);

WebElement passwordField=driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
passwordField.sendKeys(passwd); 

val signInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signin"));
signInButton.click();
```

Now, the last line of code doesn't work, since the id="signin" is not part  of the input line.

```
  <p id="signin">
    <input type="image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/sign-in-md-pri._V138360034_.gif"  width="69" alt="Sign In" value="Sign In" height="22" border="0" />
    <a id="needHelp" href="http://affiliate-program.amazon.in/gp/associates/login/help.html">Need help?</a>
  </p>
```

There is no method in the FirefoxDriver which reads element by value so that I can read value="Sign In" . I tried reading the element by Jsoup, convert to string and cast to Selenium Web element, but I get error.

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

How can I possibly make the signInButton.click() work?

Comment: why don't you provide an id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an ID to the button, or use a different selector. For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#signin input"));
```

Comment: I am doing this on my local machine where the firefox  browser pops-up, the  username and password gets entered and Sign-in button is clicked. Will this work in a remote server which doesn't have a GUI and firefox browser? Basically, I am interested in the contents after I sign in.

Comment: Err, no, you won't be able to drive Firefox wit the selenium firefox driver if you don't have Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You are not restricted to finding elements by id. Check out the Selenium Api [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) to see the other forms available for locating elements.

Below is a possible solution using XPath.

```
WebElement sigInButton = driver.findElement(by.xpath(".//p[@id='signin']/input"));
signInButton.click();
```